# Oracle expdp and impdp command?

Tags: oracle, disaster-recovery, database-tuning, impdp, expdp

I want to know the Oracle expdp and impdp command for sys user and scott/tiger user for entire database or a particular table.I will be grateful if you share me the script of expdp and impdp.I also want the script of recovery of a entire database and performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such "the" script, as in one single script that does whatever you seem to wan.  If you want to know how to use expdp and impdp, then check the documentation - the [Utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-data-pump.html#GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A) manual.

And to address one point, using expdp/impdp as SYS, the manual specifically warns ***against*** it, with this quote:

> Note:
>
> Do not start Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle
> technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized
> functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users.

And there is no single script for " recovery of a entire database".  Recovery of an entire database should actually be done with rman, using backups made by rman, not expdp.

And there is certainly no script for "performance tuning."  You are looking for simplistic answers to complex issues.  Whole books have been written on performance tuning.  Performance tuning depends on identifying the cause of poor performance, and that can come from countless unrelated sources.

Answer (score 0):

Before exporting/importing a dump of the database make sure that you have created a directory and give the permissions to read & write on this for the user that will be used to export/import.

Some basic examples for expdp & impdp:

- full database export: expdp   scott/tiger@orcl   directory=mydir dumpfile=expdp_full_db.dmp   logfile=expdp_full_db.log   full=YES;
- table export: expdp scott/tiger directory=mydir dumpfile=table_exp.dmp logfile=table_exp.log table=test
- table import: impdp scott/tiger directory=mydir dumpfile=table_exp.dmp logfile=table_exp.log tables=test

These are just some examples. Expdp and impdp provide a lot more useful options and parameters.  More details here (https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g  )

But keep in mind that EdStevens is right because there is not a 'script' that can be used to solve any problem, especially performance issues.